# How to add self gem files to Dockerfile if use official docker rails image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

The official rails image on docker hub:

https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/

I create a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM rails:onbuild

ENV RAILS_ENV=production

ADD vendor/gems/my_gem /usr/src/app/vendor/gems/my_gem

CMD ["sh", "/usr/src/app/init.sh"]
```

My init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

My Gemfile

```
...
gem 'my_gem', path: './vendor/gems/my_gem'
...
```

When I build my docker image:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

It said:

```
...
The path `/usr/src/app/vendor/gems/my_gem` does not exist.
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 13
```

The default path is `/usr/src/app`. How to add special files there?

Comment: When you are building, are in in a folder which has access to `vendor/gems/my_gem`? Can you do `ls vendor/gems/my_gem` from the folder where you do `docker build .`?

Comment: No, I added that path using Gemfile: `gem 'my_gem', path: './vendor/gems/my_gem'`. I want it search the path automatic.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on my setup, _ruby:2.4-alpine3.8_, _Rails 5.2.2_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`docker ADD`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) will add `<src>` (when it is a folder, not an url) **relative to the source directory that is being built** (the context of the build).

So you need to be sure your current directory when doing `docker build .` is also the one which includes `vendor/gems/my_gem`.

The [OP scho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5439557/scho) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686588/how-to-add-self-gem-files-to-dockerfile-if-use-official-docker-rails-image/33687360?noredirect=1#comment55150380_33687360)

> After I changed to `FROM rails:4.2.1`, it worked.

As documented in [docker rails](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/):

> This image (`rails:onbuild`) includes multiple [`ONBUILD`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) triggers which should cover most applications.
>   The build will `COPY . /usr/src/app`, `RUN bundle install`, `EXPOSE 3000`, and set the default command to `rails server`.

That means the `ADD` command was probably not needed and in conflict with the `ONBUILD` triggered `COPY`.
That differs from using `rails:4.2.1`, where the `ADD` or `COPY` is left to the `Dockerfile` specification (as opposed to `ONBUILD` triggers).

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I should build it like: `docker build -t myapp . vendor/gems/my_gem`? Sorry, I am not sure about multiple paths.

Comment: @scho it means that your `Dockerfile` must be in a folder in which you can do a `ls vendor/gems/my_gem`. The folder `vendor/gems/my_gem` must be directly below the folder where your `Dockerfile` is. The build command remains `docker build .`.

Comment: Yes. I am sure that my `vendor/gems/my_gem` and `Dockerfile` are both in the rails root path. I can do `ls vendor/gems/my_gem` in the folder which `Dockerfile` exists.

Comment: @scho in that case, `ADD` should work. Just for testing, try with `RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/vendor/gems/my_gem` first (before the ADD). And try with `ADD vendor/gems/my_gem/ /usr/src/app/vendor/gems/my_gem/` (with trailing `/`)

Comment: After I removed all the containers and images local and tried your method. The result was the same:(

Comment: No, I am using the official rails image: `FROM rails:onbuild`, so it can run default things. I can add a `RUN` in this case.

Comment: @scho OK. Can you add the `RUN` line just before the `ADD` line, in your `Dockerfile` that you are writing and which starts with `FROM rails:onbuild`?

Comment: @scho I have edited the answer to try and explain why it now works.

Comment: Thank you very much for all my questions!